# Docker swarm, http requests work very slow on overlay network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I have created overlay network like this:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable my-network
```

Then I have created my first service like this:

```
docker service create --replicas 2 --network my-network --publish 8000 --detach --name="service_a" example.com:5000/service_a:dev
```

Second service created like this:

```
docker service create  --replicas 2 --network my-network --publish 8000 --detach --name="service_b" example.com:5000/service_b:dev
```

When `Service A` makes HTTP request to `Service B`, **it takes about 3 or more seconds to finish this request**.

When I go inside one of replicas of `Service B` and make this HTTP request on istelf (via localhost), **it takes about 0.04 seconds to finish**

Why docker swarm's overlay network slows down requests like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer to my own question to help other people.

This problem was solved by upgrading Linux kernel version from `4.X` to last version of `5.X` of host machine

This was solved by using info from [this thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35082)